# How make iterator that keep some value inside itself?

Tags: python, iterator, cycle

First code:

```
for i in range(2,4):
  q = i
  print(list(q+j for j in range(q)))
```

Returns:
*[2,3]
[3,4,5]*

BUT second code:

```
zzz=[]
for i in range(2,4):
  q = i
  zzz.append(q+j for j in range(q))

for i in zzz:
  print(list(i))
```

Returns:
*[3,4]
[3,4,5]*

Why the results are different?
How to make the iterator keep the **q** value inside(in second code)?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *make the iterator keep the q value inside*?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? what output would you like to get?

Comment: pls try  res=[(q+j) for j in range(q)]

Comment: It's different because Python closures are *late binding*, but it's hard to tell what the best solution is with such abstract context.

Comment: I guess I got what you are saying. If you are executing all that code (both of them) on the same script and sequentially, the last value of `q` will be `3` after the first loop finishes. `q` will remain defined unless you `del q` before the second loop starts. In other words, you are asking why `q` is not a `local` variable inside each `for` loop, right?

Comment: And it is really strange indeed. Even issuing a `del q` before the second loop starts, the results are the same you are getting. Can anyone else explain that? Looks like a bug in `range()` maybe.

Comment: SRG I do not want a finished list.
I want an iterator in a list which will unpack in [[2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]

Comment: I want use variable i in iterator. But when i get out of the loop my iterator in list zzz does not work correctly!

Comment: After loop I want see in zzz:
[(2+j) for j in range(2),
 (3+j) for j in range(3)]

But I see:
[[(3+j) for j in range(3),
 (3+j) for j in range(3)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want generator in your list `zzz`, you can define a function that returns this generator, for example:

```
def get_generator(q):
    return (q+j for j in range(q))

zzz=[]
for i in range(2,4):
  zzz.append(get_generator(i))

for i in zzz:
  print(list(i))
```

Prints:

```
[2, 3]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Life hack) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
zzz=[]
for i in range(2,4):
  q = i
  zzz.append([q+j for j in range(q)])

for i in zzz:
  print(list(i))
```

This would yield the desired result.
Note the squared brackets in the `zzz.append([...])`. This evaluates the generator expression in a list. The `(...)` syntax is for a generator with lazy execution which will use the last value of `q`. Read here for more info https://code-maven.com/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expression

Comment: Thanks. But I want in zzz generator, NOT list...(type(zzz[0]) must be 'generator')